# how to change button position dynamically in relative layout

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change button's position in .java file when it is clicked.
The button is in relative layout.

When button is clicked button I want button to go below the textview.
how to set it below the textview?

Thanks all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) yourButton
            .getLayoutParams();
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, yourTextView);
    yourButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```